# Wizard submit button problem, I think this form wizard problem in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wizard

Submit Button not work on this wizard, I think this form wizard problem in js. When i click submit button but not work. Then I inspect the submit button, there was a submit button code like this...

```
<a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Sumit</a>
```

But i need button type submit. Please help me to solve it...

Check this problem here: sdaminul.com/wizard/this.html

**Html**

```
<form action="form.php" id="wizard">

    <h2></h2>
    <section>
        <div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Tell us about Yourself</h4>
                <div class="default-form contact-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name2" value="" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="date" name="dob" id="dateofbirth">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <h2></h2>
    <section>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Language</h4>
                <div class="tags-default mb-4">
                    <input type="text" name="lang" value="English" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add language" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <h2></h2>
    <section>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Address</h4>
                <div class="default-form contact-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="address1" value="" placeholder="Address 1" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="address2" value="" placeholder="Address 2" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

and this is form wizard javascript code.
**JS**

```
(function($) {

    $("#wizard").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        enableAllSteps: true,
        transitionEffectSpeed: 700,
          labels: {
            finish: "Submit",
            next: "Next",
            previous: "Previous"
        }
    });
    $('.wizard > .steps li a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().prevAll().addClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().nextAll().removeClass('checked');
    });
    // Custome Jquery Step Button
    $('.forward').click(function(){
        $("#wizard").steps('next');
    })
    $('.backward').click(function(){
        $("#wizard").steps('previous');
    })
    // Select Dropdown
    $('html').click(function() {
        $('.select .dropdown').hide(); 
    });
    $('.select').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.select .select-control').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    })    
    $('.select .dropdown li').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggle();
        var text = $(this).attr('rel');
        $(this).parent().prev().find('div').text(text);
    })

})(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#finish" role="menuitem">Sumit</a>
```

This will not submit your form unless it have a `type="submit"`

You can trigger your form by adding `type="submit"` or manually trigger it via `jQuery`

```
$('[href="#finish"]').click(function() {
    $('#wizard').submit();
})
```